# Как отправить картинку telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Скажите, как сделать так, чтобы при определенном сообщении юзера бот отправлял фото.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import time
import math
from urllib.request import urlopen

print('Бот запущен')
# Создаем экземпляр бота
bot = telebot.TeleBot('5374997789:AAFiW1JFXT8A8m_xZJms5BRDPqxc8wvrLo4')
# Функция, обрабатывающая команду /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    mess = f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}!Я формулознайка,наилучший бот- помощник в поиске формул по математике , выбери что ты хочешь:'
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True, row_width=2)
    poisk = types.KeyboardButton('Начать поиск:')
    admin = types.KeyboardButton('Связь с разработчиком')
    podderzchka = types.KeyboardButton('Поддержать разработку')
    spisoksokr = types.KeyboardButton('Список сокращений:')
    bistriypoisk = types.KeyboardButton('Быстрый поиск:')
    kalculator = types.KeyboardButton('Калькулятор кв. уравнений')
    mess = f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}!Я формулознайка,наилучший бот- помощник в поиске формул по математике , выбери что ты хочешь:' 
    markup.add(poisk, admin, podderzchka, spisoksokr, bistriypoisk, kalculator)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, parse_mode = 'html', reply_markup=markup)



user_num1 = ''
user_num2 = ''
user_num3 = ''
discr = ''
korni = None 


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def bot_message(message):
    mess2 = '''Треуг.(Тр.)➡️Треугольник\nКв.➡️Квадрат\nПрямоуг.➡️Прямоугольник(-ый)\nОкр.➡️Окружность(круг)\nВпис.➡️Вписанный\nОпис.➡️Описанный\nПрил.➡️Прилежащая\nРавноб.➡️Равнобедренный\nКат.➡️Катет\nГипот.➡️Гипотенуза\nСтор.➡️Стороны\nИзв.➡️Изввестный(-ая)\nH(h)➡️Высота в общей геометрии\nS(s)➡️Площадь в общей геометрии\nL➡️Сторона в общей геометрии\nM(m)➡️Медиана в общей геометрии\nПроизв.➡️Произвольный(ого)\nПолуп.➡️Полупериметр\nОсн.➡️Основние/основа\nЧ/з➡️Через\nР-но➡️Ровно\nРавтост.➡️Равносторонний'''
    mess1 = 'Поддержите разработку если считаете это нужным, это поможет проэкту существовать и развиваться Карта ПриватБанка: 5168 7559 0884 1170 Спасибо заранее!'
    mess3 = 'Связь с разработчиком: @MarcoPopa'
    mess4 = 'P.s после каждого ответа бота можете сразу продолжать искать другие формулы. Введи название формулы  ниже'
    mess5 = 'Введи ниже переменную а'
    mess6 = 'Введи переменную b'
    mess7 = 'Введи переменную с'
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Поддержать разработку':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess1)
        elif message.text =='Список сокращений:':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess2)
        elif message.text == 'Связь с разработчиком':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess3)
        elif message.text == 'Начать поиск:':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess4)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'photo')
def get_user_photo(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, "https://i.imgur.com/ofwPfHE.png")












bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте. У вас было так, что с одной стороны юзер должен прислать фото и одновременно с этим текст. Но поля text, при условии что юзер отправил фото, у него не будет(ну или оно пустое), потому ваша проверка будет `False`.
Короче, либо вы получаете текст, как я сделал ниже. Либо всё таки `photo`, но проверка должна быть по `message.caption`.

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'photo12')
def get_user_photo(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, "https://i.imgur.com/ofwPfHE.png")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD1.
Замените своё

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def get_user_photo(message):
    if message.text == 'photo':
        photo1 = urlopen('https://i.imgur.com/ofwPfHE.png')
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'https://i.imgur.com/ofwPfHE.png')
```

На то что написал я и всё у вас будет работать.

Comment: может в коде ошибка,не помогло никак,я тут в другом вопросе показал его https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1427442/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f

Comment: @MarcoPolo Что значит не помогло? Как вы пытаетесь сделать это?

Comment: Оно у вас не будет работать, так как вы хотите чтобы юзер вам отправил фото, но при этом делаете проверку на поле `text` которое будет None.

Comment: не полчается,код ошибки не видит,но по слову photo фото не отправляет

Comment: а как мне тогда сделать,чтобы пользователь написал photo и ем пришло это фото?

Comment: Заменить мое `func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'photo12'` на `func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'photo'`

Comment: Так, а чего вы хотели добиться этой фразой `if message.text == 'photo12':`? Я ведь от этого отталкивался, когда писал код

Comment: типо если ползователь введет слово фото,то покажется фото,как то так

Comment: Я о том что в вашем примере вы требовали не photo а photo12

Comment: дада,это я понял,но до сих пор бот сажем так молчит)

Comment: Обновите вопрос, и покажите как ваш код выглядит сейчас, вы меня запутали

Comment: и я не знаю что делать(

Comment: переделал,посмотрите,ибо все видосы пересмотрел и чтото не получается(

Comment: Ааа... Так вот в чем проблема. Перетащите мой хендлер выше вашего. Фишка в том что ваш хендлер впитывает в себя весь текст, и в итоге мой игнорируется.

Comment: Старайтесь не использовать пустые хендлеры, вы будете часто мучаться от таких проблем

Comment: `@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])` это тоже пустой

Comment: ура!!!!,спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: Закрывайте, вопрос, нажав на галочку слева от ответа

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
photo1 = open('https://imgur.com/a/qMOk5jg', 'rb')
bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
```

заменить на

```
bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'https://imgur.com/a/qMOk5jg')
```

Ваш код используется если изображение находится на компьютере, а если отправлять через ссылку то по другому немного.

Answer (score 0):

Функция `open` работает с файлами, а не адресами в сети, но у нее есть аналог - `urlopen`

Попробуйте так:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
...

photo1 = urlopen('https://i.imgur.com/ofwPfHE.png')
bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
```

Comment: ничего не помогло,в плане код ошибки не видит,а сам бот просто игнорирует слово photo12

Comment: @MarcoPolo, хм.. в `https://imgur.com/a/qMOk5jg` у вас не картинка, а страница сайта, где среди тегов html есть картинка, посмотрел там и ссылка на картинку будет `https://i.imgur.com/ofwPfHE.png`, ее и указывайте. Обновил ответ

Comment: не помогло,может в коде ошибка,может его скинуть сюда?

Comment: @MarcoPolo, сейчас не могу, только поздно вечером (у меня сейчас 13 часов :) )

Comment: @MarcoPolo, в принципе, вам уже ответил oleksandrigo. Похоже, проблема в вашем коде, а именно в том, что у вас обработчик ловит картинки, а функции обработчика вы смотрите на поле текста, которое похоже всегда пустое. Вам или проверку на текст убрать, или обработчиком сделать текстовое сообщение

Comment: я поменял вот на код oleksandrigo, но результата нет -_-

Comment: @MarcoPolo, похоже, моя помощь уже не нужна :)